# android.permission.BATTERY_STATS usage

Tags: java, android, power-management

I'm exploring the Android API options about the battery. what possibilities grants the permission **android.permission.BATTERY_STATS**. I know how to use it if I can read the android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED intent for the battery levels without declare such permission. Maybe I'm missing something

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This permission is used internal to Android -- AFAIK, SDK applications gain nothing by requesting it.