# Get a BroadcastReceiver to outlive it's Activity

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I work on an Android app, what should simply post some information about the battery in the notification-bar. I started this project like all the tutorials advised:

- I created a BroadcastReceiver. It handles the UI stuff.
- Then i created an IntentFilter, what filters only the
  ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED intents
- Then i simply registered the IntentFilter and the BroadcastReceiver instances
  with the registerReceiver() method of my main Activity.

It works really fine, until the Activity (what registered the two) stops. By stoping i mean, i press the back button on the phone, and i assume the onStop() or/and onDestroy() methods get called.

My question is, how could i get the BroadcastReceiver to run after the Activity is finished, and only stop recieving, when i 'Force close' the app?

**UPDATE:**

Okay, from the previous answers i think, what i need to do, is start my BroadcastReciever from the manifest file, and not from the Activity. This is what i tried to do, but it simply doesn't start recieving:

```
<receiver android:name="com.battery.indicator.BatteryReciever" android:enabled="true" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" ></action>
    </intent-filter> 
</receiver>
```

The  name attribute is the whole package-path to my Reciever class.
The actions name is what Eclipse's intellisense found. All of this is in the `<application></application>` part of the xml.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create  service and register your receiver in the Manifest.  Then Android will wake up and call your receiver even if your app is currently closed.

Comment: Could you show me where to do what? Or could you provide a link, what explains what you just said? It's the first time i'm working with a BroadcastReciever, and i never used Services before, so i don't really know what i'm doing.

Comment: Check these two links:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html  and    http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/

Answer (score 0):

If you declare your BroadcastReceiver in the Manifest (rather than the code) and let if receive Boot completed, it will always be alive.

Like this in your manifest file:

```
        <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">  
         <intent-filter>  
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />  
         </intent-filter>  
    </receiver>
```

Note: you need this permission to do that:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Comment: Will this run completely outside the application, or if i force close the app the reciever closes as well?

Comment: You really don't need the boot complete if you are not doing anything in between the handling of the BATTERY change broadcasts.  You only need to be woken up when those are sent and simply adding the broadcast intent filter to the manifest for the Battery broadcasts will do it. Otherwise you are just taking up memory doing nothing in between.  Now what I don't remember is if your service need to be active to keep the notification in the notification bar.  Then you might need this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help or not, but here is how I setup my manifest.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com./apk/res/android"
          package="com.namespace"
          versionCode, etc>

   //List permissions you use, looks like there is one for battery stats
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BATTERY_STATS" />

   <application>
     <receiver android:name=".broadcast_recievers.BatteryReciever">
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.BATTERY_CHANGED" />
     </receiver>
   </application>
</manifest>
```

The main difference I want to illustrate is you declare your project namespace/package in the manifest tag and then declare the path to the class in the receiver name. In my example I would have a class named BatteryReciever located in com.namespace.broadcast_recievers.

You'll have to do research to determine if you need to include the permission or not. This [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225926/android-permission-battery-stats-usage) post suggests that you do not.